# Unable to install Ops Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-ops-agent

I'm having issues with installing Ops Agent on individual VM. It will stuck in a `Pending: Ops Agent is installing.` state and then go `Ops Agent undetected`.

`google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh` is installed and active.

When I checked the log, it states `google-cloud-ops-agent runs successfully.`

VM is not using legacy Agents.

Just in case, I have also added `Logs Writer` and `Metric Monitoring` role.

Here is the procedure outlined:
https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation

**--Added Info:--**.
OS `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`
OS `version 11`
Machine type `e2-standard-2`
This is the version installed
`dpkg-query --show --showformat \ '${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture} ${Status}\n' \ google-cloud-ops-agent google-cloud-ops-agent 2.18.2~debian11 amd64 install ok installed`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your OS details and machine type in order to attempt an issue reproduction?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielRobledoAhumada OS `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)` OS `version 11` machine type `e2-standard-2`. I didn't have issues installing Ops Agent in the past. I tried again today and the problem still persists.

Comment: I have successfully installed the Ops Agent in the same VM machine type and OS with no issues. Did you install the agent directly using the VM CLI or the Google Cloud console?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielRobledoAhumada I tried both following this https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#cloud-monitoring and https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#compute-engine  Can you advise where else should I look into to troubleshoot?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, I'm using a bitnami wordpress solution

Comment: @GabrielRobledoAhumada Not sure if it is helpful, I added the agent version to the OP.

Comment: @CuppaCoffee It always makes a difference to mention details, Gabriel above attempted to reproduce your environment but didn't succeed in reproducing the same issue. You should update your question to include the detailed guide you followed (steps) and the bitnami wordpress solution if you expect proper assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @HectorMartinezRodriguez I do appreciate the help from GabrielRobledoAhumada but if the info I have provided is not detailed enough, i have no other information to add. The exact steps taken are provided by the link, do I have to copy and paste the same document here again?

Comment: In this case I recommend you to open a support case as this issue seems to be unique to your project, you can do that through the [Support hub page](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Hi CuppaCoffee, I faced the same problem. But after I changed the image version from Debian 11 to Debian 10 with a standard persistent disk it started to install successfully.